# vb .net plugin support for sonar v3.5.1

Tags: vb.net, maven, sonarqube

We use sonarqube v3.5.1 to measure quality for our soure code. When we setup sonar initially, v3.5.1 was the latest version of sonar. We wanted to analyze VB .NET source code. Since it is a commerical plugin, we tried only trial version that time and cannot analyze for longer time. But now we got the license from sonarsource for VB .NET and ready to use. But now i cannot find any suitable download link of sonar VB .NET plugin that suits my sonar v3.5.1. When i tried to install latest version of VB .NET plugin, my current sonar version doesn't support (sonar not starting). We cannot migrate now to newer version of sonar. Please help us in getting this resolved.

Also we use maven to analyze our project. Please post a sample pom.xml to analyze vb .net source code.

Thanks
Murthy.

Comment: If you now have a license, then surely that entitles you to technical support?

Comment: How can i get the technical support ?

Comment: Can anyone provide me solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bought a license, then you should know the support mailing list address.

Otherwise, please contact us through the following form: http://www.sonarsource.com/get-contact/

Comment: Yeah.. but i wanted to know if there is any support for sonar v3.5.1 with VB .NET plugin?